# The at() matcher has been deprecated

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, deprecated

> The at() matcher has been deprecated. It will be removed in PHPUnit 10. Please refactor your test to not rely on the order in which methods are invoked.

I need a replacement for my code, please help me. Thank you.

```php
public function GetIceptraxModelMock($method = array(), $multipleMethodSame = false)
{
    if (empty($method) || $multipleMethodSame) {
        $modelMethods = array("SendHttpRequest");
    } else {
        $modelMethods = array_keys($method);
    }

    //create iceptrax model mock
    $iceptraxModelMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Firstwap\Altamides\Modules\Iceptrax\Http\IceptraxModel::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods($modelMethods)
        ->getMock();

    //mock return value of iceptrax model methods
    foreach($method as $methods => $returnVal) {
        if ($returnVal === 'exception') {
            $iceptraxModelMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method($methods)
                ->will($this->throwException(new \Exception()));
        } elseif ($multipleMethodSame) {
            foreach ($modelMethods as $value) {
                $iceptraxModelMock->expects($this->at($methods))
                    ->method($value)
                    ->willReturn($returnVal);
            }
        } else {
            //without parameter
            $iceptraxModelMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method($methods)
                ->will($this->returnValue($returnVal));
        }
    }

    return $iceptraxModelMock;
}
```

Comment: Rewrite the test without it. Compare https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4297

Comment: I already try but can't find the replacement at() mathcer

Comment: Thanks for your attention, my last comment was a bit short about it, this is exactly what you should have found referenced for comparison. To prolong my previous comment if you're looking for an additional confirmation: **Rewrite the test without it as there is _no replacement for the `at()` matcher_.**

Comment: what u means rewrite the test ? rewrite the code ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. For additional confirmation feel free to also compare with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_(programming)